# What do I need to know to pass the A1 or A2 exams from Goethe Institut?

Tags: learning, proficiency-test

Can someone share what I need to know to pass the A1 or A2 exams from Goethe Institut?

For instance, do I need to know

- all cases (nominative, accusative, dative, genitive)?
- the past form of every verb?
- the separable prefix *ver-*?
- etc.

Comment: Related: [Suggestions on preparing for the Zertifikat Deutsch (internationally accepted certificate in German) exam](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4099/1224)

Comment: Following the link of [Takkat's answer to the related question](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/4100/1224) leads also to more information about A1 and A2. Hier der Direktlink für [A1 Übungsmaterial](http://www.goethe.de/lrn/prj/pba/bes/ft1/mat/deindex.htm)

Comment: Do you have a test of A1.
See you.

Comment: Am I supposed to make sentences from the given flash cards in the German A1 exam? I have an exam this month. Can somebody please give me some info? I am very nervous...

Answer (score 3):

I have learned German starting  from A1 and till C1 level. If you want to pass either of A1 or A2 exam you do not have to know a lot. At A1 level you should be able to use simple sentence structures and basic grammar and little vocabulary. This is a little description of what you should know:

*After completing the A2 level, students can understand sentences and frequently used expressions related to areas of most immediate relevance (e.g. very basic personal and family information, shopping, local geography, employment). They will be able to communicate in simple tasks requiring a direct exchange of information on familiar and routine matters. Students can describe in simple terms aspects of his/her background, immediate environment and matters in areas of immediate need.*

Answer (score 3):

I often read that passing A1 or A2 is easy. I recommend to take a look at the [practice material and information published by the Goethe Institute](http://www.goethe.de/lrn/prj/pba/bes/ft1/mat/enindex.htm). If people have not seen the above samples, and just self study from 1-2 books for 3 months, maybe they will not pass.

So maybe what is easy for some is not same to other people.

Comment: +1 thx for the link