# Resources for the Goethe-Zertifikat A1

Tags: learning, resource, proficiency-test

Are there any coursebooks for the Goethe-Zertifikat A1?
I have found some material on their website, but that seems quite limited. thanks

Comment: @HubertSchölnast A1 is the lowest level in CEFR, The Großes Deutsches Sprachdiplom corresponds to C2 in the CEFR, i.e. the highest level. That's a huge difference with regard to the learning materials you need. Definitely *not* a duplicate.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-pass-the-a1-or-a2-exams-from-goethe-institut

Answer (score -2):

I am using a book called Vorsprung.  [https://www.amazon.com/Vorsprung-Communicative-Introduction-Language-Culture/dp/1133937608](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133937608)
It covers lots of material, starting from total beginner to B1 or B2.
Also good online exercises (that complement Vorsprung but are helpful regardless of whatever course/book you chose): http://www.nthuleen.com/teach.html